# Marionette Behaviors: Add dynamic options

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views, behavior

How can I add a behavior to my view with a variable as an option?
In my case, the variable I want to use is an option of the view, but, when I tried this:

```
behaviors: {
    prodMessage: {
        profile: this.options.userdata.attributes._userid
    }
},
```

I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined
```

I think that is because this take place in the construction rather than the initilization.

So, do you have any workaround to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your version gets executed during application loading. So `this` does not actually point to the view instance, but probably to `window` object. To have `this` point to the view, you need defer the specification of the behaviors, so that it get executed when the view instance is constructed:

``

```
behaviors: function() {
  return {
    prodMessage: {
      profile: this.options.userdata.attributes._userid
    }
  };
}
```

``

See this [codepen](http://codepen.io/juodaspaulius/pen/jbwwvL) for full version.

---

Alternative option is to have the behavior access the view through `this.view`:

```
prodMessage = Marionette.Behavior.extend({
  onShow: function() {
    alert(this.view.options.userdata.attributes._userid);
  }
});
```

Comment: I know it's weird, but the first method doesn't work for me. any ideas why would that be?